# Container does not shrink when inner text wraps

Tags: html, css, overflow, width, nowrap

I am trying to have two elements horizontally aligned where the one on the left has text that may wrap then sizing the screen, and the one on the right allows for no wrapping. When the content wraps, the first element maintains the width of content + (wrapped word - pixels causing wrapping), instead of shrinking to fit the content.

I created an example on Fiddle where you can see the grey background of the first element having no content for a couple of pixels, instead of resizing to only include the text.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 760px;
}

.item {
  background-color: grey;
  width: fit-content;
  block-size: fit-content;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span> This Text to auto-adjust to only fit the content when wrapping</span></div>
  <div class="item2">This should be right next to last word on first line on the left</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/acemanu412/o9bumhk0/15/)

Is there a way of achieving an auto-size to only fit-content on resizing of the screen so the 2 element stays as close to the text of the first one as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Elements inside a flexbox has `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` set by default, which allows them to bypass the basic `width` and `height` properties.

To solve this problem, just disable `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`:

```css
.item {
    background-color: grey;
    width: fit-content;
    block-size: fit-content;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rouchen! Your suggestion seemed to work by basically fixing the width of the container to make it bigger to be able to fit the content. That's is good to know but, in the case I want to explore, the width should not be big enough to include the whole content, but should be small enough to cause the text to wrap, and remove the extra space to the right of the content (In left-to-right languages) after wrapping.

Comment: If you want a fixed size, just set `width` to an absolute value such as `200px` or `50%`